# Como sumar variables de diferentes clases, en el mismo JFrame

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

//Voy iniciando en esto, no se como utilizar las variables de otras clases que se encuentran en el mismo frame, ya que necesito que sumen el resultado y lo muestren en una etiqueta.

```
}                                           

private void spinnerYeloxStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                          
    int cantidadYelo = (int) spinnerYelox.getValue();
    int precioYelox = 20;
    int totalY = cantidadYelo * precioYelox;
    int SubtotaldeB =totalY;
    etiSubYelox.setText(String.valueOf(SubtotaldeB));
}                                         

private void spinnerPapasStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                          
    int cantidadPapas = (int) spinnerPapas.getValue();
    int precioPapas = 16;
    int totalP = cantidadPapas * precioPapas;
    int SubtotaldeC = totalP;
    etiSubPapas.setText(String.valueOf(SubtotaldeC));
}                                         

private void spinnerAwaStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                        
    int cantidadAwa = (int) spinnerAwa.getValue();
    int precioAwa = 5;
    int totalAwa = cantidadAwa * precioAwa;
    int SubtotaldeD = totalAwa ;
    etiSubAwa.setText(String.valueOf(SubtotaldeD));
}                                       

private void spinnerCafeStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                         
    int cantidadCafe = (int) spinnerCafe.getValue();
    int precioCafe = 18;
    int totalCafe = cantidadCafe * precioCafe;
    int SubtotaldeF = totalCafe;

    etiSubCafe.setText(String.valueOf(SubtotaldeF));
```

//Quiero hacer que se sumen todos los subtotales

```
 private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    
    etiTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

//y guardarlos ahi

Comment: cada variable que as declarado solo puede ser accedida dentro del método donde están declaradas {} , debes hacer uso de varibles tipo global si es que estan dentro de una misma clase y si provienen de otra clase hacer uso de getters [revisa](http://aprendiendoconjava.blogspot.com/2011/07/variables-locales-y-globales.html)

Comment: Super sencillo, como es que no lo note jejeje, muchas gracias amigo!!!!
creí que necesitaba de getters, pero para lo que hare ahora si, asi que muchas gracias.

Comment: Otro camino sería pedirle a **etiSubCafe**, **etiSubYelox**, **etiSubPapas** y **etiSubAwa**, los valores contenidos, transformarlos a int, y realizar las suma.